# How do I define a range in a column with a known first cell and ending right before a specific value cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to define a variable column range that will be set with a first cell being known and the last cell being one cell above the cell containing "Net Amount"

```
Dim cell As Object
Dim P1RNG As Range
Dim PFRNG As Range
Dim PRNG As Range

    Worksheets("Sales Orders").Activate
    For Each cell In Sheet1.Cells
            If cell.Value = "Q300103176" Then
                'Find first Part number
                Set P1RNG = cell.Offset(29, -24)
                'Find Last Part Number
                Set PFRNG =
                'Set part number range
                Set PRNG = Range("P1RNG":"PFRNG")
                PRNG.Select
            End If
    Next
```

that's the code i've worked up so far I just don't know how to find the final cell in the range (PFRNG) which will be right above the cell containing "Net Amount". I cannot jsut find the cell containing "Net Amount" and make it offset one up because there are multiple cells containing Net Amount in this sheet. It must specifically be the one that comes next below the first cell(P1RNG).
There might also be a totally better way to do this without using any of that code that I made which I am open to learning about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range.Find` is more efficient than iterating over all the cells.

```
Dim rValue As Range, rNetAmount As Range, PRNG As Range

With Worksheets("Sales Orders").Cells
    Set rValue = .Find(What:="Q300103176", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not rValue Is Nothing Then
        Set rNetAmount = .Find(What:="Net Amount", After:=rValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rNetAmount Is Nothing Then

            Set PRNG = .Range(rValue, rNetAmount.Offset(-1))

        End If
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I would replace the last test on rvalue by a test on rNetAmount

Comment: This was helpful. The first find did not work to get the value that I wanted but I think that was unclear in my original most and I was easily able to fix that but the second part did exactly what I wanted thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Find()* with an offset:

```
Sub PartOfColumn()
    Dim B As Range, Startt As Range, WhatToFind As String
    Dim rTemp As Range
    Set B = Range("B:B")
    Set Startt = Range("B5")
    WhatToFind = "Net Amount"

    Set rTemp = B.Find(What:=WhatToFind, After:=Startt).Offset(-1, 0)
    Set rfinal = Range(Startt, rTemp)
    MsgBox rfinal.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

in this case:

[image]

Here we start with **B5** and look downwards to find the first instance of "Net Amount"..............then backup one cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function l_locate_last_value(Optional str_value As String = "Net Amount")

    Dim my_cell         As Range
    Dim l_lowest        As Long: l_lowest = -1

    For Each my_cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If my_cell = str_value And my_cell.Row > l_lowest Then
            l_lowest = my_cell.Row
        End If
    Next my_cell

    l_locate_last_value = l_lowest


End Function
```

Later, you can always substract -1 from the result.
I am using UsedRange, as far as it is faster (at least on my PC) than iterating all cells.

Answer (score 0):

an `AutoFilter()` approach

```
Function GetRange(firstCell As Range, stringAfter As String) As Range
    With Intersect(firstCell.EntireColumn, firstCell.Parent.UsedRange)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=stringAfter
        Set GetRange = .Parent.Range(firstCell, .Resize(.Rows.COUNT - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1))
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

to be used in you "main" code like:

```
Dim PRNG  As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Orders")
    Set PRNG = GetRange(.Range("B5"), "Net Amount")
    MsgBox PRNG.Address

    '... other code
End With
```